# How do I implement this "counter" on a Hash Table in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashtable

I'm creating this Hash Table in JavaScript and I want it warn me each time I'm adding existing values in the array. I tried my own implementation, but it isn't working.

```
function hashFunction(s,tableSize){
    let hash = 17;

    for(let i = 0; i<s.length; i++){
        hash = (13*hash * s.charCodeAt(i)) % tableSize;
    }

    return hash; 
};

class HashTable {

    table = new Array(2000);
    numItems  = 0;
    loadFactor = this.numItems/this.table.length;

    setItem = (key,value)=>{
        const idx = hashFunction(key, this.table.length);
        if(this.table.includes(key)){
            return "already exists"
        }else this.numItems++
        if(this.table[idx]){
            this.table[idx].push([key,value])
        }else this.table[idx]=[[key,value]];

    };

    getItem = (key)=>{
        const idx = hashFunction(key,this.table.length);
        if(!this.table[idx]){
            return "Key doesn't exist";
        }else
         return this.table[idx].find(x=>x[0]===key)[1];
    };
};

let myHash = new HashTable

myHash.setItem("first","daniel")
myHash.setItem("last","esposito")
myHash.setItem("age","21")
myHash.setItem("height","1,90")
```

Comment: What does “it isn’t working quite well” mean? Error (which) or wrong output after some operations (which)?

Comment: Why are you implementing your own hash table instead of using something built-in to Javascript (e.g. object or Set)?

Comment: On this line `this.table.includes(key)`, you're passing the `key` to `table.includes`, but `table.includes` will only tell you if the array contains the provided _value_ (`this.table`'s values are not your hash keys, they are `[key, value]` arrays). If you want to efficiently test if a value exists in the array (i.e. without searching the array on each check), then you'll have to create another hash table that is indexed by the values. Then test against that.

Comment: Also, `13 * hash * s.charCodeAt(i)` was probably supposed to be `13 * hash + s.charCodeAt(i)`? Otherwise as soon as you have the factors of 2000, the hash is zero forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be beneficial to review implementing pseudo code and existing implementations. There were numerous errors which can summarized as the original implementation failing to correctly handle pairs within a bucket.

Here is a working update which salvages some of the structure while discarding most of the inconsistent and/or incorrect implementation - I've left comments as reference points to understand *why* the original was incorrect. The code has been structured to illustrate access/creation of buckets, access/creation of pairs within the buckets, and behavior selection depending on the case.

YMMV.

```
function hashFunction(s, tableSize){
    let hash = 17;

    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
        hash = (13 * hash + s.charCodeAt(i)) % tableSize;
        //                ^-- Ry suggests the original * is a typo.
    }

    return hash; 
};

class HashTable {

  // I've eliminated 'load factor' to cover a basic implementation.
  // See rebalancing, good table size selection, alternative collision
  // resolution strategies, etc.
  // This implementation might pass a CS101 course.

  // Yes, for THIS EXAMPLE the TABLE SIZE IS CHOSEN AS 2.
  // This ensures that there are multiple items per bucket
  // which guarantees the collision resolution paths are invoked.
  // This is a terrible choice in practice.
  table = new Array(2);
  numItems = 0;

  setItem = (key, value)=>{
    const idx = hashFunction(key, this.table.length);
    // set/get should ONLY access simple properties or
    // a BUCKET from the hash code as top-level structures.
    // (Using table.includes(..) here is fundamentally INCORRECT.)
    let bucket = this.table[idx];
    if (bucket) {
      // Existing bucket. Search in HERE to see if the key exists.
      // This should generally be the same code as the "get".
      let pair = bucket.find(x => x[0] === key);
      if (pair) {
        // Same pair, update value.
        pair[1] = value;
        return false; // "existing"
      } else {
        // Add new pair to bucket.
        bucket.push([key, value]);
        this.numItems += 1;
        return true; // "new"
      }
    } else {
      // Create a new bucket and item pair.
      this.table[idx] = [[key, value]];
      this.numItems += 1;
      return true; // "new"
    }
  };

  getItem = (key) =>{
    const idx = hashFunction(key, this.table.length);
    // Code should match close to 'set'
    let bucket = this.table[idx];
    if (bucket) {
      let pair = bucket.find(x => x[0] === key);
      if (pair) {
        // Bucket exists and key exists within bucket.
        return pair[1];
      }
    }

    // The result should be the same if the key doesn't exist because
    // bucket is not found, or if the bucket is found and the
    // key does not exist within the bucket..
    return undefined;
  };
}

let myHash = new HashTable

var items = [
  ["first", "daniel"],
  ["last", "esposito"],
  ["age", 21],
  ["height", 1.9]
]

// Insert multiple values:
// Check to see inserted report true/not,
// and that the numItems is increased appropriately.
for (let run of [1, 2]) {
  for (let i of items) {
   let [k, v] = i;
   var inserted = myHash.setItem(k, v);
   var found = myHash.getItem(k) === v;
   console.log(`run=${run} key=${k} value=${v} inserted=${inserted} numItems=${myHash.numItems} found=${found}` )
  }
}
```

Output:

```
run=1 key=first value=daniel inserted=true numItems=1 found=true
run=1 key=last value=esposito inserted=true numItems=2 found=true
run=1 key=age value=21 inserted=true numItems=3 found=true
run=1 key=height value=1.9 inserted=true numItems=4 found=true
run=2 key=first value=daniel inserted=false numItems=4 found=true
run=2 key=last value=esposito inserted=false numItems=4 found=true
run=2 key=age value=21 inserted=false numItems=4 found=true
run=2 key=height value=1.9 inserted=false numItems=4 found=true
```

Comment: “Only limit to target space at the end of the generation or the hash space and quality is significantly reduced” is not right. With arbitrary-size integers, mod-n of products is the same as mod-n of mod-n products. In JavaScript, `number` is a floating-point type, so this hash implementation is actually worse.

Comment: Well, the hash function is probably typoed (see comment on the question), but I think using mod to map a hash result to a bucket is pretty common.

Comment: Alright, added that comment and made the suggestion change and.. going to leave it at that. Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: Hey everyone! thank you so much for your help and suggestions, I'm new to programming, really appreciate it, such a great community.

Answer (score -1):

`hash += (13*hash * s.charCodeAt(i)) % tableSize;`

Comment: Anyway, make sure to _explain_ answers “code snippets”, what the change is, and why it’s relevant.

Comment: code only answers are frowned upon on SO. For long term value, an explanation will help visitors learn from your answer, and determine if your solution can be applied to solve their own coding issues. Quality, well thought answers are more likely to be upvoted, as they are more helpful, and more quickly understood by more people. Please consider editing to highlight the important parts of your solution, and why.